# Couldn't share data between two multiprocesses in python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am having a problem with my code. I am using both fbchat module and discord.py module.

```
import fbchat
import discord
import multiprocessing

client = commands.Bot(commands_prefix = ';', intents = intents)

#This class is for the fbchat which listens to events from fb messenger.
class onSend(Client):
    def onMessage(self, author_id, message_object, thread_id, thread_type, **kwargs):
        if message_object.text == 'multiprocess' and thread_type == ThreadType.GROUP:
            channel = client.get_channel(test_channel)
            channel.send("working")

#runs the fbchat listener
def run_client():
    fbchat_start = onSend(username, password)
    fbchat_start.listen()

#runs the discord bot
def run_bot():
    client.run(Acess_token)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target = run_bot)
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = run_client)
    p.start()
    p1.start()
```

My problem is when I run the code, it results to 'nonetype' object has no attribute 'send'. Basing on the error, I can say that the first process doesn't share data with the other process. 'Channel = client.get_channel' returns nothing. I don't know if you guys can understand what I mean but what I really think is that I should share the data between the two processes. How do I do that.? Thanks

Comment: Are you expecting data to be shared by the fact that the two bits of code are accessing the same `client` object? If so, then that's your problem.  They aren't.  Since the two bits of code are running in different processes, they can't be sharing an in-memory object.  I apologize in advance if this is not the crux of your problem.  I don't know the Discord API at all.  I just know that many beginning users of Multiprocessing forget that you can't share objects between processes like you can between threads.

Comment: Oh Ok OK thhanks, But are you saying that you can share data between threads? Should I Use threading instead?

Comment: Yes.  Threads run in the same address space, so they can access the same objects directly.  This can get you into trouble, like if two threads are trying to modify the same object at the same time.  There are tools that help you deal with this, like locks and mutexes. - I don't know enough about what you're doing to recommend that you switch to threads.  You could try it.  The two are very similar in how they are used.